# Why do I divide Z by W in a perspective projection in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, math, matrix

I guess this is more a math question than it is an OpenGL one, but I digress. Anyways, if the whole purpose of the perspective divide is to get usable x and y coordinates, why bother dividing z by w? Also how do I get w in the first place?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Perspective_projection

Comment: This has to do with homogenous coordinates. They mapping R^3 -> R^4 is   clearly not one-to-one. The w factor can be 'cannonized' to 1. But one applying 4x4 matrix operator the resulted 'w' may change. If I recall correctly, one advantage of homogenous-coordinates is to have translation as a linear operator.

Comment: IMO the shortest answer is - because dividing z by w ultimately affects x and y values. In the next step in gpu pipeline you divide x and y by z to have 2d NDC space that can be transformed into screen coordinates.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Actually, the explanation has much more to do with the limitations of the depth buffer than it does math.

At its simplest, "the depth buffer is a texture in which each on-screen pixel is assigned a grayscale value depending on its distance from the camera. This allows visual effects to easily alter with distance." <sup>[Source](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Depth_buffer)</sup>

More accurately, a depth buffer is a texture containing the value of *z*/*w* for each [fragment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/8981/41200), where:

- *Z* is the distance from the near clipping plane to the fragment.
- *W* is the distance from the camera to the fragment.

In the following diagram illustrating the relationship between *z*, *w*, and *z*/*w*, *n* is equal to the `zNear` parameter passed to [`gluPerspective`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml), or an equivalent function, and *f* is equal to the `zFar` parameter passed to the same function.

[image: Diagram illustrating the relationship between *z*, *w*, and *z*/*w*]

At a glance, this system look unintuitive.  But as a result, *z*/*w* is always a floating-point value between 0 and 1 (0/*n* and *f*/*f*), and can therefore be represented as a single channel of a texture.

A second important note: the depth buffer is nonlinear, meaning an object exactly in between the near and far clipping planes is nowhere near a value of 0.5 in the depth buffer.  As shown above, it would correlate to a value of 0.999 in the depth buffer.  Depending on your view, this could be good or bad; you may want the depth buffer to be more detailed close-up (which it is), or offer even detail throughout (which it doesn't).

TL;DR:

- You divide *z* by *w* so it is always in the range [0, 1].
- *W* is the distance from the camera to the fragment.

Comment: I really don't quite agree with this answer, the question pertains to a purely mathematical problem, what is explained here is an opengl and z-buffer algorithm implementation detail (the depth buffer).

Comment: The z in NDC is in range [-1, 1], not [0, 1] which is DirectX convention.

Comment: why at the furthest fragment, both w and z are f? There is "n" distance between w and z starting points. Thank you.

Comment: `Z is the distance from the near clipping plane to the fragment. W is the distance from the camera to the fragment.` I think I can safely assume that these sentences apply in DirectX as well.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically if you forget to divide by w which contains -z, then you'll notice that points or objects won't appear smaller the further they are from the camera.